# fork() и pipe()

Tags: c, unix, fifo

Есть задание по программировению на С, в UNIX системах:

> Создать параллельный процесс, используя только fork.Организовать обмен 
>   информацией между процессами через каналы таким образом,
>   чтобы родительский процесс читал из канала в цикле, пока
>   не встретится конец файла (порожденный процесс может записывать в
>   канал информацию, читаемую им из стандартного входного потока).

Вот текст программы:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    char buf;
    pipe( fd );

    switch( fork() ){
        case -1:
            perror( "fork()" );
            exit( 1 );
        case 0:
            close(fd[0]);
            while (read(0, &buf, 1) > 0) {
                write(fd[1], &buf, 1);
            }
            write(1, "Death child\n", 12);
            close(fd[1]);
            break;
        default:
            close(fd[1]);
            while (read(fd[0], &buf, 1) > 0) {
                write(1, &buf, 1);
            }
            write(1, "Death parent\n", 12);
            close(fd[0]);
            wait(NULL);
            break;
    }
}
```

Я его полностью разобрал( внес правки, которые сделали код более понятным, по моему мнению). Но я не могу понять
1.Почему после каждой итерации циклов
В child:

```
while (read(0, &buf, 1) > 0) {
                    write(fd[1], &buf, 1);
                }
```

В parent:

```
while (read(fd[0], &buf, 1) > 0) {
                    write(1, &buf, 1);
                }
```

у меня идет переход на другой процесс ( на родительский или дочерний )?
2.Как избежать бесконечного ожидания родительским процессом чтения из 
пустого канала?

Comment: упс, ошибка, сейчас исправлю

Comment: ...и ещё одна: у вас чтением из канала занимается не родитель, а потомок. И ожидает данных именно он. Второй вопрос выглядит бессмысленным.

Comment: Не, родительский процесс обрабатывается в default, он и читает из иеннованного канала, а вопрос состоит в том как предотвратить ожидане чтения если канал пуст
Потом читает из обычного канала ввода read( 0.... )

Comment: А, точно, `0` же возвращается потомку. Мой косяк.

Comment: А ещё я не вижу в коде использования именованного канала. Именованный существует в файловой системе и доступ к нему осуществляется аналогично доступу к файлам. У вас же в коде просто канал/пайп.

Comment: pipe создает пару файловых описателей, указывающих на запись inode именованного канала ( https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=pipe&category=2&russian=0 )

Comment: Это ошибка перевода. Откройте оригинал.

Comment: Хмм, да, увидел ошибку, хоть в англе и не секу. Но нам нужно как раз использовать pipe() для межпроцессоного взаимодействия

Comment: Понимаю. Просто указываю на нестыковку в вопросе. Поправьте. (PS: меж**процесс**ного)

Comment: Сейчас исправлю нестыковку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Программа работает абсолютно нормально. Что же касается вопросов:

1. У меня идет переход на другой процесс ( на родительский или дочерний )?
2. Как избежать бесконечного ожидания родительским процессом чтения из пустого канала?

То они ставят в тупик... В памяти вашего компа ОДНОВРЕМЕННО  присутствуют два процесса. Какой из них выполняется каким именно процессором и в какое время - это решает ядро операционки.

Если процесс **не** готов к выполнению (например - ждёт ввода), то он висит.
Какой процесс первым придёт в готовность, тот и продолжит своё выполнение.

Вот и весь преход... С точки зрения ядра - абсолютно не важно, родительский, или дочерний.

А насчёт ввода из **пустого** канала - это Вы вообще - как представляете?! Если канал пуст, как из него можно что-то ввести? Вот программа и висит на операции *read*.